# Using Replace to only replace a small portion of a string

Tags: excel, vba

I am reading data from an text file, and I am trying to format it to match a Defined Name for a cell. The defined name is `89NL_10ETH_A` and the string is `89NL 10ETH A` but with a bunch of spaces after it. I used `Replace()` to convert spaces into "_", but all of the spaces at the end are converted to underscores. How can I trim the spaces off of a fixed length, mind you `Trim()` did not work because of the fixed length?

This is how I am currently doing it

```
getProduct = Replace(Replace(Mid(Ln, 40, 24), "#", ""), "%", "")
```

Comment: `Application.Trim` I believe works for VBA. Instead using the replace, after the Trim you could use `Split(STR, " ")`and finally `Join(arrSTR, "_")`

Comment: `Trim()` works. Use it first, before replacing the remaining spaces.

Comment: I see what i was doing wrong. I had the `Mid` length too long and it was picking up a period from the next column that i wasn't seeing, and why it looked like my `Trim` wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AndyG stated, you can use Replace() with Trim().

You can use it with a text string

```
getProduct = Replace(Trim("89NL 10ETH A           "), " ", "_")
MsgBox getProduct
```

Or, with a cell value

```
getProduct = Replace(Trim(Range("A1").Value), " ", "_")
MsgBox getProduct
```

Comment: This correct. It is what I already had in place, but the `Mid` length was too long and i was picking up a period that I did not see, which gave the illusion that `Trim()` wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Just `Trim` before you `Replace`:

```
Sub TrimTest()

    Dim InputString As String
    InputString = "  89NL 10ETH A    "

    Debug.Print Replace$(Trim$(InputString), " ", "_")

End Sub
```

`Trim` removes the spaces from `"  89NL 10ETH A    "` in the beginning and end `"89NL 10ETH A"` so the spaces in between can be replaced by underscore `"89NL_10ETH_A"`.

Comment: There is RTrim as well but the difference is probably minuscule.

Comment: @AndyG Yes but just in case the OP needs to trim both. I would use `LTrim` or `RTrim` only in the rare cases where either left or right spaces should **not** be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This way works fine:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim STR As String, arrSTR

    STR = "89NL 10ETH A    "
    arrSTR = Split(Application.Trim(STR), " ")
    MsgBox Join(arrSTR, "_")


End Sub
```

Comment: Why split and join when you can just replace?

Comment: Thought replace is a worksheetfunction, so doing that was faster?

Comment: @Damian Well there is the [WorksheetFunction.Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.replace) (*Replaces part of a text string, based on the number of characters you specify, with a different text string.*) and the [Replace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) (*Returns a string, in which a specified substring has been replaced with another substring*), but they do completely different things if you compare the documentation carefully.

Comment: I wouldn't know without investigating.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i've checked, yes... the worksheetfunction works for cells and the replace function works for a single string. There is something i've learn today

Comment: @Damian actually that's not correct. The worksheetfunction substitutes a specific amount of characters in a specific position of a string (dosn't need to be a cell). It is not a "search/replace" like the replace function is. See the example in the link of the worksheetfunction. • The replace function searches for a specific substring and replaces it by another.

Comment: @Damian Don't mix it up with the [WorksheetFunction.Substitute method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.substitute). • And yes, the names of these worksheetfunctions are indeed very confusing. ;)

Comment: As I was answering here i've answered myself, I was refereing to `Cells.Replace` sorry.

Comment: @Damian Well, yet another replace method ^^ didn't have had this one in mind.